# the product of a matrix and a permutation matrix

Tags: matrices, permutations, random-matrices

Can a permutation matrix ($P$) be used to change the rank of another matrix ($M$)?
Is there any literature to this effect, or to the contrary?

I've tried a few small examples and the resulting matrix ($M_2$) seems to always have the same rank as the input matrix ($M$)

$M_2 = M P$

Comment: Are there any special matrices that I can use to "alter" the rank of M? I've tried "constricting" the permutation around the diagonal but this still produces the same rank (with less perturbation of the original matrix), for similar reasons as above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: The rank of a matrix is the number of linearly independent row vectors, or of linearly independent column vectors. Now think about what a permutation matrix does to the row or column vectors in the matrix if you multiply it from left or right.

Comment: A permutation matrix is full rank. I see that each column of the permutation matrix samples each row of M. So the output would be the rank of M. Thank you. Are there any special matrices that I can use to "alter" the rank of M? I've tried "constricting" the permutation around the diagonal but this still produces the same rank (with less perturbation of the original matrix), for similar reasons as above.

Comment: Well, a very special matrix to alter the rank of $M$ is the matrix with only zero entries. Also, think about diagonal matrices with only ones and zeros on the diagonal. What do those do to $M$? More generally: What would you have to do to reduce the number of linearly independent vectors in $M$? And how might this be related to the eigenvalues of the matrix you multiply with $M$?

Comment: ok - thanks again. By alternating 1s and 0s down the diagonal I essentially null out entire rows of M. This reduces the rank but I've "deleted" information. I was hoping for a way to reorganize M into a lower rank structure... without deleting information. In order to do so, I would have to convert a previously linearly independent vector into a linear combination of an existing vector (fewer eigenvalues). I was just curious if there was a known/automatic way to do this via matrix multiplications. Maybe this is asking for too much?

Comment: Well, think about it this way: How many vectors do you need to describe a matrix of rank $k$? (to make it more concrete, say you want to write it as $v_1v_1^T + \ldots + v_mv_m^T$; what is the minimum $m$ you need?) And now consider in the light of this what it means to lower the rank. Can you imagine to do that without throwing away information?

Comment: I get you. Forgive my stubbornness. I lower the rank by changing a LI vector into a LC of another LI vector. I keep track of these changes such that I can bring the matrix back. Why: I want to manipulate a matrix into a lower rank form while keeping track of the changes required. I apply these changes to a sparse matrix S whose values came from M. I assume S is now in a "lower rank form". I apply a low-rank-matrix-completion algorithm to reconstruct the missing values. I apply the original changes in reverse. Sorry if this was long, I thought you deserved the bigger picture. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** If $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ and $B\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ then 
$$\mathrm{rank} (AB)=\mathrm{rank} (A)=\mathrm{rank} (BA)$$

Comment: thank you. what is G L_n? I'm not familiar with this notation...

Comment: $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is the group of invertible matrices.